# Java AWT Font and exploding font style variety

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I am trying to use the font Helvetica Neue with my app. However, the font is represented by multiple files, apparently each containing a style. I have installed the fonts into the system (Windows) and I can see them usable in Notepad and other apps. The styles of the font are like "Thin", "ThinItalic", "Light", "UltraLight", "UltraLight", "Black", "BlackItalic" and so on, which are properly selectable in apps like Notepad under their correct names.

But with AWT Font, I can only see the following options to select a style: `Font.BOLD`, `Font.PLAIN`, `Font.ITALIC`. How do I properly access the styles variety of the Helvetica Neue font and make them usable in my application?

Comment: Font has Attributes (required to iterate), btw [DYM??? this Helvetica Neue from....](http://crossgraphicideas.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/helvetica-neue-font-free-download-complete-family/)

Comment: @mKorbel: Yes, I mean that font. Our UI designer has given me the UI layout in terms of these various styles, so now I am trying to realize how do I implement it within the program... I have found the API for the FontAttributes and indeed there are all these values  (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) however, I cannot find a good example of using it...

Comment: [for example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/visual-font-designer/) by @Darryl Burke

Comment: @mKorbel: thanks for the reference! Gonna go check it out!